# Is there a non-manual way to create a directory-like structure of Angular 6 router paths?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-router

I am setting up an Angular 6 app.  A component uses a directory-like structure and the directories can contain other directories, nested just like they are on disk.  The component will display a list of what is in the directory, both files and other directories, and if the user clicks on a directory I want the app to nest one level down and for the URL to reflect that.  In other words, I want the router to keep state information in the URL so the user can use the back button in the browser and have other normal navigation.

I can accomplish this with the following code in the Router module:

```
{ path: 'show-dir/:dir1', component: ViewDirectoryComponent },
{ path: 'show-dir/:dir1/:dir2', component: ViewDirectoryComponent },
{ path: 'show-dir/:dir1/:dir2/:dir3', component: ViewDirectoryComponent },
{ path: 'show-dir/:dir1/:dir2/:dir3/:dir4', component: ViewDirectoryComponent }
....
```

However, this is limiting because I am manually entering each level and don't want to have 100 manual entries (and then a limit of 100 nested directories ...)

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem. Maybe if you configure all those paths as children to a root one, you could accomplish what you need without having to manually repeat paths.

Something like:

```
{
    path: 'show-dir', children: [
        { path: '**', component: ViewDirectoryComponent }
    ]
}
```

You have the root *show-dir* path and for children you specify ** which will match any route and load the view directory component. Use the ActivatedRoute to fetch and parse the url to show the relevant contents.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, this is an interesting idea.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Indeed, it worked.  I can get the list of segments that was passed with the "this.route.snapshot.url" array.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to loop over all the configured routes, you can get the routes from router.config

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.router.config.length; i++) {
        var routePath:string = this.router.config[i].path;
        console.log(routePath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan - I don't want to loop through EXISTING routePaths, I realized my title may have been a bit misleading in this regard so I changed it.